# Open a file on Sharepoint online via Powershell and append data to it and save it back to sharepoint

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I am now able to connect to SharePoint Online and I can upload a file all via PowerShell.

```
$siteurl="https://hpwqld.sharepoint.com/sites/isd/teamsites/os"
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteurl
Add-PnPFile -Path D:\delme\test.csv -Folder "Directory and Operating Systems"
```

So can I do the following in Powershell.

1. Connect to Sharepoint  open the file test.csv and then append new data to it and save it back to SharePoint.

One was would be to:

1. connect download the file
2. update the file
3. upload the file (over writing the existing file in SharePoint).

But I think that is not a clean way to do it.

Comment: How is in not clean exactly? Is there a [code smell](https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/smells)? I assume it's that you want to append or create the file in which case have a look at [sp](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/50106/appending-text-to-an-spfile-in-document-library-creating-file-if-necessary)

Comment: [ps-file-manip-with-sp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43350575/how-to-use-powershell-to-download-files-from-sharepoint)

Comment: thanks for that I will look at it tomorrow.

Comment: All good. that site helped out heaps. Thanks