# Sharepoint powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I am trying to use powershell to get the document folders for all of my company's sharepoint sites to track files.

I am able to log into sharpoint and pull up all of our subsites but I cannot get to the files in the subsites. I end up getting .dll files.
My script will list all of the subsites but I cannot get the documents and folders inside.

```
Connect-SPOService -url https://mycompany-admin.sharepoint.us

$sites = Get-SPOSite
foreach ($site in $sites) { 
      Get-ChildItem
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use PowerShell to download files from SharePoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43350575/how-to-use-powershell-to-download-files-from-sharepoint)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that - `Get-ChildItem` is for getting files on your system; it won't work in SharePoint. What you need to do instead is something like this to get items from each list:

```bash
$items = Get-SPOListItem -List $list
```

where `$list` is a reference to your list.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to get all folders inside each subsite by looping through all subsites and using *Get-SPOFolder*:

```
Connect-SPOService -url https://mycompany-admin.sharepoint.us

$sites = Get-SPOSite
foreach ($site in $sites) { 
      $subsites = Get-SPOSite -Identity $site.Url -Limit All
      foreach ($subsite in $subsites) {
            Write-Host "Processing site $($subsite.Url)"
            $folders = Get-SPOFolder -SiteRelativeUrl $subsite.ServerRelativeUrl -Recursive
            foreach ($folder in $folders) {
                  Write-Host "Folder: $($folder.ServerRelativeUrl)"
                  …………
            }
      }
}
```